# Exact callback url redirection is not working after SSO login

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, jhipster

I have a button on login page which redirects to SSO login page. The SSO is different domain. Once I successfully loggedin it is redirecting to home page.

Scenario 1 :

```
            Request url :  localhost:6000  action:  popup to sign in and Onclick button
            Routing page:  SSO login username and password  action: On successful login
            Redirecting to : localhost:6000 [Home page]
```

Scenario 2:

```
            Request url :  localhost:6000/ask   action: popup to sign in and Onclick button
            Routing page:  SSO login username and password  action: On successful login
            Redirecting to : localhost:6000 [Home page]
```

Scenario 3:

```
            Request url :  localhost:6000/ask   action: if SSO already sign in 
            Routing page: will login without routing to SSO page
            Redirecting to : localhost: 6000/ask
```

In these three scenarios, Both 1 and 3 is working perfectly. In second, after successful SSO login the page should redirect to localhost:6000/ask but it is redirecting to home page instead. Some suggestions on this issue will be greatly helpful.

Environment: React, SpringBoot

Thank you!!

Comment: is there any redirect happening at pop up? If there is then sso might be receiving home page Url while receiving login request.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by SSO in JHipster? Which authentication type did you select? KeyCloak? Okta?

Comment: yes, button on the pop up redirects to SSO page. the sso page receiving referrer / callback url as a home instead of enter url. please refer scenario 2 above.

Comment: I am using Oauth and Keycloak configuration. I like to know how to pass the callback url from front end and set it as callback url in server/backend configuration file